# Laravel queue processed event listener doesn't contain my user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using the Laravel 8 job and queue system. I'm dispatching a job called `FetchBeamData` within one of my controllers and am passing it the currently logged in user.

Then, inside of my `AppServiceProvider` I'm using the `JobProcessed` event that will trigger some custom functionality.

But when I `unserialize` my payload, I'm not seeing my user at all in there, what am I missing?

My user is passed into my job's constructor as an optional argument:

```php
/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($beam, $user = null)
{
    $this->beam = $beam;
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

And when I dispatch the job, I run:

```php
FetchBeamData::dispatch($beam, Auth::user());
```

Inside of my listener, I expect to see the user in there:

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
        $payload = $event->job->payload();

        Log::debug('=== AFTER ===', [
            'connectionName' => $event->connectionName,
            'job' => $event->job,
            'payload' => unserialize($payload['data']['command'])
        ]);
    });
}
```

What am I missing to access this, the current output is:

```json
{
   "connectionName":"database",
   "job":{
      "Illuminate\\Queue\\Jobs\\DatabaseJob":[
         
      ]
   },
   "payload":{
      "App\\Jobs\\FetchBeamData":{
         "job":null,
         "connection":null,
         "queue":"on-demand-runs-now",
         "chainConnection":null,
         "chainQueue":null,
         "chainCatchCallbacks":null,
         "delay":null,
         "afterCommit":null,
         "middleware":[
            
         ],
         "chained":[
            
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> this should do the trick

```
public $beam;
public $user;

public function __construct($beam, $user = null)
{
  $this->beam = $beam;
  $this->user = $user;
```